# Hosting an ongoing process in IIS

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis

Is there a way to host an ongoing process in IIS?  Let's say i'm writing an invoicing web site and every so often I need to send out scheduled invoices.  This is really part of my invoicing app and I'd like it to be deployed as part of my invoicing app, by copying files to the web server.  I don't want the deployment headaches or the awkward separation that would come with writing this as a Windows Service.  Is there a way this can be done in IIS?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your simplest solution would be to develop a simple console EXE that does its thing and you schedule it in Scheduled Tasks.  Updates to the EXE are done the same way as the web app, just overwrite the file.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [Best way to run scheduled tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542804/asp-netbest-way-to-run-scheduled-tasks/542815#542815), it'd probably fit your use case.