# ASP.net auction expiration mechanism

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to realize auction expiration? Make it inactive after 1-3-5 days? Something like eBay?

Any links for information would be appreciated,
I have "active" boolean field in my auction table

Comment: What you need are requirements, not programming advice.

Comment: hmmmm...auction_start_date and auction_end_date fields in database?

Comment: i just want to find mechanizm for doing this. I do have this fields

Comment: So you want some sort of scheduled task to check for the closed status and update your database.

Comment: so..where do I do this? auctionDetail.aspx? every postback? that is what i dont know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of ways to do this. I think the question was very difficult to understand and that's why you didn't get any answers. Check out this question to see if it gets you on the right track: [Best way to run scheduled tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542804/asp-netbest-way-to-run-scheduled-tasks/542831#542831)