# Sending Periodically Email From Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net

I want to send an email to the admin from my asp.net web application daily at 8:00 am. How to send an email that I know. But how to send it periodically that I doubt. Not through SQL Server. I have written my logic in Application_Start in Global.asax Is this is right?

Comment: Check this post out as this might help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542804/asp-netbest-way-to-run-scheduled-tasks

Comment: This is Too Broad for Stack Overflow, I will vote to close.

Answer (score 1):

- Use [Quartz Scheduler](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/index.html).
- Or **write a windows service** that can do this for you,
- Or register to call your asp.net page that sends the email in **Windows Scheduler** everyday at 8 AM.

Answer (score 0):

You have a page with the logic to send mail but which doesn't send response to the client. Or you can send some response like a success message or whatever you like.

Or instead of a page a web service method would do fine.

Once you have either setup and in production, you need to write a vbscript (*.vbs) which makes a call to the web service or aspx page url. You'll have to schedule this script to run periodically using the windows scheduler (Start -> Run -> Type "tasks" in the run dialog).

Or you'd have to use write a windows service which would do the same thing. You'd have to make use of Timers, HttpWebRequest, and HttpWebResponse classes inside the service.