# Thread in Global.asax does not work after publishing the web site

Tags: asp.net, publish, global-asax, web-deployment

I am developing a web application where I have implemented job scheduler using Global.asax. I have used thread to start the job for particular duration.

It works fine if I run the application through visual studio. But when I publish and deploy it to the server the thread doesn't work.

Please help me to resolve this issue. Is there any alternative for this.

Please find the sample code below,

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadFunc));
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Name = "ThreadFunc";
        thread.Start();
    }

    protected void ThreadFunc()
    {
        System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer();
        t.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(TimerWorker);
        t.Interval = 10000;
        t.Enabled = true;
        t.AutoReset = true;
        t.Start();
    }

    protected void TimerWorker(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //work args
    }
```

Thanks,

Vijay

Comment: @Ravi - Please find edited sample code.

Comment: seems good. may be IIS Issue?? why cant u use Services, instead of threads??  as @MK. anwserd in his link .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think spawning a thread in global.asax is a good idea.  Please see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542804/asp-netbest-way-to-run-scheduled-tasks) for better solutions.

Comment: Now I have written a windows service to perform scheduler job.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no activity on your site for a period of time, it is shut down automatically.

To circumvent this, google "Keep asp.net site alive"

But you'll find a bunch of duct-tape like hacks.  I would change the architecture.