# asp.net mvc running async thread

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, web

I'm running an async thread with the use of Task.Factory.StartNew(() to generate sitemaps.
My problem is that when I call my method:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => generator.CreateSiteMapForSite
```

it builds the sitemaps every time.

In my method I check that it only needs to regenerate the files if it is older than one hour. 
Even though it still regenerate the files per each request, is there a way to handle this in a async thread ?

Comment: If you want help on code level, you should really post more code, for now I don't really get what you actually need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap around the task in an `if` and generate a new one if the sitemap doesn't exist or if exists read the file's modified datetime see if it's older than 1 hour.

The better solution is to setup a scheduled task to run every hour and rebuild the sitemap.

Checkout [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542804/best-way-to-run-scheduled-tasks) to find more on scheduled tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Since C# 5.0 you can use the async and the await keywords, have a look at this MSDN page for more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx