# How to automatically send email at a certain time ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, sendmail

**Situation:** I need to send notification emails every Monday at 9 a.m to all employees, remind them to due the last week report.

I basically know how to "send email in ASP.NET" (I implemented the *contact us* form on our website, so *"sending email service"* basically will be executed when people hit submit button) but I had a hard time to figure out how to make it automatically execute at a certain time, maybe I need a scheduler or something like that, I don't use any database here?

Somebody who have done it before could give a right direction?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to run scheduled tasks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542804/best-way-to-run-scheduled-tasks)

Comment: have a look at this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49996/Schedule-Email-Through-ASP-NET-or-Schedule-Tasks-U

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For scheduling tasks I always recommend [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/). However, you should know that there are certain issues when you try to implement scheduler in asp.net application (in my opinion it is better to implement it in windows service). If you implement it in asp.net application remember about application pool idle time (set it to high value or disable automatic pool recycling) since pool must be active when the scheduler needs to execute the task.

Comment: OK, I googled before asking this question and Windows Service seems to be a good solution, I will give it a shot. I expected that I can find some detailed directions in here but maybe I need get my a** up and do it :D, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should create a windows service which will do the job

Comment: Thanks I will research about Windows Service