# Why static variable dies in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer, static, scheduled-tasks

We know that **static variable alive** until the **application alive**.

For example, we can count the number of visitor with a single `static int` variable.

```
private static int numberOfVisitors = 0;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    numberOfVisitors++;
}
```

If the above sentences are right, we can define a `static Timer` and we expect the `Elapsed` event fire forever.

So, I wrote this application:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private static System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(100);
    private static int numberOfTicks = 0;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = numberOfTicks.ToString();
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Start();
    }

    void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        numberOfTicks++;

    }
}
```

After clicking `Button1`, for some minutes, the `Lable1.Text` increase per millisecond, but when 15 minutes have passed, this lable shows just `0`.

Why and **what can I do for the forever timer**?

Comment: "We know that static variable alive until the application alive." - No, static variables are retained as long as the AppDomain is. So if a new AppDomain is created, you'll get new variables...

Comment: When IIS recycles the app pool, static variables are reset

Comment: @JonSkeet So what is the answer of: **what can I do for the forever timer?**

Comment: Don't use ASP.NET for scheduled tasks - it's as simple as that. There's no "forever" in ASP.NET - you're in a hosted application that's being routinely recycled. If you really have no other option, it is possible to handle this, but I'd avoid it unless absolutely necessary. There's frameworks to help you if needed. Oh, and your code is not thread-safe.

Comment: @MehdiKhademloo you could initialize your timer when the application starts, and persist the intermediate values somewhere else (DB?). But perhaps you should explain more what exactly you'd like to do.

Comment: @Zidad the problem is not the value. The problem is the **Fire the timer elapsed event forever**. This example is just a example. Not more

Comment: @MehdiKhademloo you can't, or at least you shouldn't. IIS can at any time decide to kill your process if it isn't used. Are you running on Azure? There's other options there...

Comment: @Luaan The threading issure is not important now because this example is just an example and the full problem is another one. I think there is no other choice, I have to run a function at anytime of a day. So there is no option?

Comment: Not from within ASP.NET. Unless there's a request, your application may not run at all.

Comment: @MehdiKhademloo have a look at this post: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx

Answer (score 1):

> Static variables persist for the life of the app domain.  So the two
>   things that will cause your static variables to 'reset' is an app
>   domain restart or the use of a new class.

you are losing your static variable in your aspx page because asp.net decides to recompile your page in new class.

take a look at this link [Understanding ASP.NET Dynamic Compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

so, if you want to perform some task in a particular interval there are many solutions i think you should take a look at this [Running task in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542804/best-way-to-run-scheduled-tasks)
or this ones seems to be a better idea [asp.net long running interval tasks](https://github.com/b9chris/ASP.Net-Long-Running-Interval-Task)