# Sheduler Task In ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a web application in ASP.NET MVC , I am newbeei,
I have a usecase 
I am entering some values in table along with status, say"Active",
After sometime say half an hour those status should be updated to "Inactive" in a background task , I am using MS Sql

Please me provide me with a solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to run scheduled tasks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542804/best-way-to-run-scheduled-tasks)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use Windows service for this and schedule it to run each half hour check the following examples :

http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/C-Sharp/Timer-Objects-in-Windows-Services-with-C-NET/

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/naresh.avari/develop-and-install-a-windows-service-in-C-Sharp/