# Quartz.net - Do I've to run web project URL every time I restart Machine?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, scheduled-tasks, quartz.net

I've web Project (asp.net) that send emails Using quartz.net. Task schedule running normally on server machine and I've window task schedule running on same machine
when I restart the machine:
web project stopped sending emails
but windows task schedule running normally
Do I've to run web project URL every time I restart Machine , because it's run normally when I did that ?

Comment: I'm not sure if english is your second language OR you just wrote the question too fast.  asp.net is not trustworthy for a service.  A "real' windows-service is probably better.  Here is a hybrid work around : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542804/best-way-to-run-scheduled-tasks

Comment: First :I use web app to send mails and it hosted on iis of course. using Quartz I wrote code on aspx.cs page to create task schedule .
Second: windows task schedule running different job
I believe my English is very simple and clear now
http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/254/scheduled-tasks-in-asp-net-with-quartz-net

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37051200/quartz-for-asp-net-gets-killed-by-iis-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes granadaCoder this was what happen exactly with me So, After complete my project I create Task schedule that Run my hosted project to invoke other schedule on iis