# Server side project C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have full access to server i want to run C# code on server automatically and every minute it should repeat. Is there any techniques or web services allow allow asp.net project regarding same?
I cant able to find correct reference. Post a link here if possible. I have ready code that allows my work on Page_Load. But I want to make such like , whole code should be Running every 5 minutes.

## RFID #Attendance #RealTime

Comment: look at this link https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Similar question to what you have asked.
[Best way to run scheduled tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542804/best-way-to-run-scheduled-tasks)

> All of my tasks (which need to be scheduled) for a website are kept
>   within the website and called from a special page. I then wrote a
>   simple Windows service which calls this page every so often. Once the
>   page runs it returns a value. If I know there is more work to be done,
>   I run the page again, right away, otherwise I run it in a little
>   while. This has worked really well for me and keeps all my task logic
>   with the web code. Before writing the simple Windows service, I used
>   Windows scheduler to call the page every x minutes.
>
> Another convenient way to run this is to use a monitoring service like
>   Pingdom. Point their http check to the page which runs your service
>   code. Have the page return results which then can be used to trigger
>   Pingdom to send alert messages when something isn't right.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options:

1- put the code in a web service, and create a consumer windows service to invoke it every N minutes.

2- put your code in a windows service and execute it from a timer.

3- Make a thread in the web-page (Not recommended) to execute your code.

Hope that helps you