# Setting up a Daily Job in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, scheduled-tasks, jobs

I have an ASP.NET Webform application (C#) configured in an IIS server. The application connects to a database on another server for its normal operation.

Now I need to create an auto emailing system. This system should check certain conditions in the database, and based on that it should send automatic emails to certain email ids. I have an smtp mail server, and I know how to do the automatic emailing using C#.

This emailing should be triggered daily at a certain time. So how will I configure such a job in my server? What are my options?

I am pretty new to the ASP world. Thanks for help.

Comment: You can use a Windows Service or a Console Application in Scheduled Task.

Comment: You can use `Quartz.Net `. for more info: https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/

Comment: You can create your own scheduler, which there should be more than a few tutorials on. As an alternative you can use scheduling libraries like [FluentScheduler](https://github.com/fluentscheduler/FluentScheduler), [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) or [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/). All of them should support recurring jobs, that can be scheduled daily, weekly etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to run scheduled tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542804/best-way-to-run-scheduled-tasks)

Comment: I have used [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) in the past to send all my emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your want to keep the logic and code of your mailing system separated from your other application, you could also generate a separate project (a C#.net console application which generates a .exe file), and launch it at your desired time intervals using Windows Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) and create a [recurring job(cron job)](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/performing-recurrent-tasks.html) to check the db if the mails need to be sent... if so,  en queue Hangfire jobs for each mail that needs to be sent.
It works extremely well, I have implemented this in the past.

If you decide to go this route, let me know if you need some help.

Comment: Hangfire FTW. I also recommend it!

Comment: Thanks for this. Right now, i might be opting for a simple console application because of time constraints. But certainly, i will keep this in mind for next time.

Answer (score 0):

Try exploring Scheduled Tasks in window server. You can write a console application in c# and then point your schedule task to run the console application at a certain time.

If you really want to use asp.net website then you can write a powershell script to call the asp.net web service and use schedule task to run the script at a certain time.