# How to set telemetry frequency to send a message to iot device using c#

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-iot-hub

I have following code which sends data to iot device successfully.
Now i want to set telemetry timespan to send data continuously how to configure that any guidance ?

```
  private static async void SendDeviceToCloudMessagesAsync(string deviceid , string deviceKey)
            {
                deviceClient = DeviceClient.Create("hostname", new DeviceAuthenticationWithRegistrySymmetricKey(deviceid, deviceKey), Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.TransportType.Mqtt);

                double minTemperature = 20;
                double minHumidity = 60;
                int messageId = 1;
                Random rand = new Random();
                while (true)
                {
                    double currentTemperature = minTemperature + rand.NextDouble() * 15;
                    double currentHumidity = minHumidity + rand.NextDouble() * 20;
                    var telemetryDataPoint = new
                    {
                        messageId = messageId++,
                        deviceId = deviceid,
                        temperature = currentTemperature,
                        humidity = currentHumidity
                    };
                    var messageString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(telemetryDataPoint);
                    var message = new Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(messageString));
                    message.Properties.Add("temperatureAlert", (currentTemperature > 30) ? "true" : "false");
                    await deviceClient.SendEventAsync(message);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} > Sending message: {1}", DateTime.Now, messageString);
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                }
            }
```

> basically here i have used `while (true)` instead of this i want to
>   set
>
> > 1.how often to send telemetry from each device input format is HH MM SS
> >
> > 2.How long simulation will run inout format is HH MM SS
> >     [UI screen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-accelerators/media/quickstart-device-simulation-deploy/solutiondashboard-expanded.png#lightbox)

Comment: Are you just asking for how to schedule this with a recurring iteration? ie. [`System.Threading.Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=netframework-4.7.2) ?

Comment: this is my web application mvc and i have UI also to setup the parameters like this so yes how to set up the schedule. UI screen https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-accelerators/media/quickstart-device-simulation-deploy/solutiondashboard-expanded.png#lightbox

Comment: I don't think you can schedule a task *in* an asp.net app (that includes MVC). See also [Best way to run scheduled tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/542804/1260204). You would generally do this in a windows service or similar depending on your hosting solution.

Comment: oh i have hosted this web app into azurewebsites i think i can create a webjob but how exactly the above code i can configure i dint understand it. thanks in advance

Comment: Probably you are interesting about the IoT Hub quotas and throttling, so the following document described it:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-quotas-throttling

Comment: also, I do recommend to read an Azure Device Twin concept & features: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-device-twins

Comment: thanks a lot for doc link but any other blog you recommend for implementation ?

Comment: have a look at this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/tutorial-device-twins